# How to determine whether remote network device is available?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, network-programming, tcp

I find many answers for how to determine if e.g. iPhone is connected to internet, but am at a loss for finding a solution to determining whether a specific remote network device is available.

I have been using this solution, but it is not so good:

```
-(bool)isNetworkDeviceAvailable{

bool ok = true;
const char *servIP = [[txtIPAddress stringValue] UTF8String];

in_port_t servPort = 5001;

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sock < 0){
    NSLog(@"setDAC: Socket creation failed\n");
    ok = false;
}
struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
if(ok){
    if(rtnVal == 0){
        NSLog(@"setDAC: inet_pton() failed: invalid address string\n");
        ok = false;
    }
    else if (rtnVal < 0){
        NSLog(@"setDAC: inet_pton() failed\n");
        ok = false;
    }
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
}
if(ok) if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){
    NSLog(@"setDAC: connection failed\n");
    ok = false;
}

if(ok){
    FILE *datastream = fdopen(sock, "r+");
    fclose(datastream);
    [lblUnavailable setHidden:YES];
}
else [lblUnavailable setHidden:NO];
return ok;
}
```

It works, but the application hangs for as much as a minute before a inaccessible device is reported.  I am sure there must be a smarter method out there, since ping does not take very long to report network inaccessible...

Thanks,

-Pete

Comment: `ping` uses the ICMP protocol ( as in **not** tcp-ip ), and your mileage may vary  since many carriers block ICMP on selected network segments. Albeit slow, your method is better.

Answer (score 1):

Add Reachability Class to your project.

```
 #import "Reachability.h"

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.example.com"];
    NetworkStatus reachabilitytoHost = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(reachabilitytoHost != NotReachable)
    {
        //reachable
    }
    else
    {
        // not reachable
    }
```

Download sample from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Also check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html

Edit: also add `SystemConfiguration` framework.

Comment: This is the same suggestion plastered everywhere for how to determine if the device you are using has network access.  However, Apple documentation [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html): "Reachability cannot tell your application if you can connect to a particular host, only that an interface is available that might allow a connection, and whether that interface is the WWAN."